# Copy and Paste Cell Contents to Different Sheet Based on Condition

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen similar posts, but nothing that has directly addressed my current problem...

I have a workbook with 2 sheets (Sheet1 and Sheet 2).  In Sheet1, there are 2 columns - column A contains part numbers from our old ERP system and column B contains weights.  In Sheet2, I have 2 columns - column A contains part numbers from our new ERP system and column B contains alias part numbers.

I would like to have a macro read in the part number in Sheet1 (which sits in column A) and see if that value exists in Sheet2 in either column A or column B.  If it finds a match, it would need to copy the corresponding weight to column C on Sheet2.

I am a novice at writing macros and I've attached a modified version of code posted to a similar problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you in advance to any replies.

```
Sub CopyCells()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim j As Long, i As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long

    Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    lastrow1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow1
        For j = 2 To lastrow2
            If sh1.Cells(i, "A").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "A").Value Or _
                sh1.Cells(i, "A").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "B").Value Then

                sh1.Cells(i, "B").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "C").Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help get you started. I am assuming you have data starting in row 1 in columns A and B of Sheet1 and Sheet2 and that you want to copy weights to Column C in Sheet2 :

```
Sub GetMatches()

    Dim PartRngSheet1 As Range, PartRngSheet2 As Range
    Dim lastRowSheet1 As Long, lastRowSheet2 As Long
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range

    lastRowSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Set PartRngSheet1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRowSheet1) 

    lastRowSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Set PartRngSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A" & lastRowSheet2)

    For Each cl In PartRngSheet1
        For Each rng In PartRngSheet2
            If (cl = rng) Or (cl = rng.Offset(0, 1)) Then
                rng.Offset(0, 2) = cl.Offset(0, 1)
            End If 
        Next rng
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate the response Remnant, but I just discovered why my original code wasn't working.  It turns out that all of the part number cells had a number of trailing spaces and because the data was coming from two different ERP systems, the number of spaces differed.  So even though the part numbers were the same, the number of additional spaces made them different and the macro couldn't recognize that.  Once I scrubbed the two sheets, my original code worked as expected and I am sure yours will as well.  Again thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: @anticedent - no problem. Just use VBA.Trim$ in your code to trim unwanted white spaces...